# Opening Hydra Heads & Other Cost Related Questions

Tags: hydra

So i have few questions here, which i wasn't able to find direct answers to.

1. Does it cost ADA from mainchain to activate/close a Hydra head ?
2. Does Hydra have similar "channel limits" as Lightning network does? as in i create a head and set limit as 5000 ADA, can that number be adjusted afterwards?
3. When im interacting with Hydra in general in which circumstances/possibilities i will be needing to use Cardano Mainnet to send/transfer/ funds.

I Tried to ask questions best to my ability based on my somewhat limited tech understanding.

Answer (score 3):

You're technical understanding seems to be quite fine and let me point you to some additional resources / answer your questions:

1. Yes. Opening and closing a Hydra head costs ADA. It depends greatly on how many participants a Head has and how much funds need to be distributed. Also, different versions of the protocol will cost differently. These benchmarks are done on each commit to `master` and should give you a rough idea how much these transactions cost: https://hydra.family/head-protocol/benchmarks/transaction-cost/
2. There is no limit in how much value you can store in a Hydra Head. However, we do limit to only commit a single UTxO per party right now (this limit will be removed eventually)
3. The `hydra-node` will need a connection to the Cardano network and submit transactions for opening/closing a Head. Furthermore, in the opening of a Hydra Head, the funds to be made usable in it will need to be "comitted" to the head in a layer 1 (mainchain) transaction.